# Good Resources for Colour Schemes?

Tags: color, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Picking colors that don't clash.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/picking-colors-that-dont-clash)

What are some good resources for getting colour schemes/palettes for your designs? I usually mix/make them myself but sometimes I need quite a lot of colours to select from, and in that case, it extends the project time by quite a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/picking-colors-that-dont-clash?

Comment: No... *Resources* for colour schemes and not ways to pick nonconflicting colours.

Comment: did you read that question? Given that it says, "What I need is a resource that will help me choose a color (or colors) that go nicely with, or provide a good accent to, whatever main color I am working with on the design."—which sounds to me like a request for, well, resources for color schemes. Or looking at it another way: how many of its eight answers *aren't* an answer to your question?

Comment: Dori is correct. This is duplicate content.

Comment: The title of the other question should probably be more general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote an article a few months ago that covers [how to choose color schemes](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/design/theory/how-to-choose-a-color-scheme-for-your-website), some resources for doing so, and some of the related psychology involved. However, if you just want something quick and dirty, check out [Colour Lovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/) and [Adobe Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com).

Comment: Very complete and resourceful article, thanks !

Comment: +1 Both Colour Lovers and Adobe Kuler are fantastic resources.

Answer (score 4):

From the answers to [Picking colors that don't clash](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/picking-colors-that-dont-clash):

- [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com)
- [How color schemes work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_scheme)
- [Simultaneous and successive contrast](http://colorusage.arc.nasa.gov/Simult_and_succ_cont.php)
- [Wucious Wung's *Principles of Color Design*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471287083)
- [Josef Albers' *Interaction of Color*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300115954)
- [Creating Your Own Color Palettes](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/08/color-theory-for-designer-part-3-creating-your-own-color-palettes/)

Comment: @Zanlok: I hope you realize that both Colour and Color are valid ways to spell the word. One is British English, and the other American English respectively.

Comment: indeed, and it's still a foolish pride thing