# Colors in Website Design

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-theory

It's not a kind of question but rather it's a kind of thing which effects a lot in web designing. 
What are some important rules to follow for making a color combination in web design?
I always fail in choosing the right and appropriate colors for my site, how can I improve this?

Any advice is much appeciated.

Comment: Look at this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/picking-colors-that-dont-clash

Comment: Is there any way you can distil this to form a question?

Comment: I'm not going to close it because, if I'm reading this right, the OP isn't asking simply for picking colors that don't clash with tools, but asking about the principles behind picking colors that don't clash. There might be a language barrier here.

Comment: Check out my article on [How To Choose A Color Scheme For Your Website](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/design/theory/how-to-choose-a-color-scheme-for-your-website).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Decide on a palette early (there have been a couple of threads about sites that generate palettes automatically). Your palette should include (but isn't necessarily limited to): a "main" color (that's complimented by the other colors you use), a contrasting font color, and one or two complimentary colors.

2) If you have a logo, the colors of the logo will probably drive the palette. If you're designing a logo for the site it'll work in the opposite direction (the colors of the site or the corporate colors will drive the logo and site colors).

3) STICK WITH YOUR PALETTE. We all have "Oooh! Shiney!" moments, but remember the idea is the colors help to unify several different ideas or areas.

4) Your palette should include other design elements - or rather, other design elements should fit within your palette. For instance, a web page featuring dark, solid colors and glossy-looking buttons will probably be okay with chrome or brushed steel elements (trim, highlights, maybe even in the logo) but stick with one "family" of metal. If you want this to be an earthier or pastel-feeling site, stick with more appropriate textures (Fabrics? Leaf or plants?).

 
5) KISS. A smaller palette will allow you to have a more unified and less-cluttered look. If you are using complimentary colors make sure they're being used to compliment - outline or fill areas that are visually distinct - rather than just being put in there to have more colors.

A book (or web site) on color theory would probably be pretty helpful; there are a couple of "must read" articles on thei site and one of them must list some good color theory books.

Answer (score 5):

As I answered previously at [Good Resources for Colour Schemes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/809/good-resources-for-colour-schemes/814#814):

> From the answers to [Picking colors that don't clash](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/picking-colors-that-dont-clash):
>
> - [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com)
> - [How color schemes work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_scheme)
> - [Simultaneous and successive contrast](http://colorusage.arc.nasa.gov/Simult_and_succ_cont.php)
> - [Wucious Wung's *Principles of Color Design*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471287083)
> - [Josef Albers' *Interaction of Color*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300115954)
> - [Creating Your Own Color Palettes](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/08/color-theory-for-designer-part-3-creating-your-own-color-palettes/)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the colors you use for your website jump out! For example, orange background and a gray template on it. I found that grey is a very good color and you can combine it with almost every color. Very much proffesional websites use gray too. And be sure to use your creativity. If you want to become designer or if you are already, it's handy to have creativity by hand.
My grandma always said if you want to become a painter, then draw the same thing every day (example: an apple) and day by day it will get better and better. Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist in color theory but I have a tip! [Colourlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com) is a great tool to choose an effective color combination. Every day community share new palettes for inspiration.

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Read as: I'm a "Colourlovers" rep and I want you to visit my site

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with color as well but sites like colourlovers.com and kuler.adobe.com help out in choosing a basic palette.  Once you have a basic palette a good site to check out is 0to255.com - it'll help you out in getting accent and gradient colors from your basic palette.