# Color matching tools

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-around-colors-i-select)

Can anyone recommend a good tool / website for finding color matches for a certain color I specify?

Until now I've been using the Photoshop's opacity / overlay blend mode to get more color variatians, but I don't think this is the way to do it :D

I think http://www.colorblender.com/ is a good example of what I'm looking for, but I want something better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex, I dont know what "something better" is to you, but what I think you are looking for is this one goodie:

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

You can use it to find complement, triad, tetrad, analogic and accented analogic colours.
You can even adjust it to take into account colour blind users and export the colour pallette.

Answer (score 4):

ColourLovers have [some nice tools](http://www.colourlovers.com/tools) that sound suitable for your needs:

Comment: colourlovers indeed

Answer (score 4):

In the "Tools You Already Have" department, Window > Extensions > Kuler allows you to enter a key color and riff on different harmonies (Monochromatic, Complementary, Triadic, etc.), and allows you to save harmonies you like and/or load them into the Swatches panel.

Comment: Also available at WWW, if you happen to lose Photoshop or are on the go: http://kuler.adobe.com/

Answer (score 3):

For variations on a base color try http://0to255.com - it's great for borders / gradients / etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Photoshop plugin that gives you color wheel functionality right inside photoshop.

http://anastasiy.com/magicpicker

Answer (score 2):

there are some links, awesome to work with, personally i use color matcher tool (link no 4) its very fine to count working color percentage with each other there are so many tools to check color consistency..

1. [Colors on the web](http://www.colorsontheweb.com/colorwizard.asp)
2. [Color match](http://www.hypergurl.com/colormatch.php)
3. [45 color tools and-resources for color](http://www.smashingapps.com/2011/05/24/45-color-tools-and-resources-for-choosing-the-best-color-palette-for-your-designs.html)
4. [Color matcher tool](http://www.colortools.net/color_matcher.html)

there are 12 other handy tools in the same  [Color matcher tool site](http://www.colortools.net/color_matcher.html)  for colors, see in left hand side such as :

```
Close Colors Tool
Color Matcher Tool
Color Picker Tool
Colors by RGB Values
Colors Mixer Tool
Combine Colors Tool
Compare Colors Tool
Make Websafe Colors
Opposite Color Tool
Random Color Tool
Text on Background
Web Safe Color Picker..
```

Hope this will help.....

Answer (score 2):

here are some online color matching tools :

- [Online color matching tool](http://www.techiequest.com/color-match-match-website-colors-with-online-color-matching-tool/)
- [color explorer](http://www.colorexplorer.com/colormatch.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

online tools : http://www.colourlovers.com/

offline tools : color schemer studio (also available for iOS )