# Is there a chart for color combinations?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, resource-recommendations, color-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-around-colors-i-select)

Is there a chart or something which shows you which color goes with with color?

For e.g. If I pick Blue, it will tell me that "Blue will go well with  Yellow"...something like that?

How do go about choosing right color combinations?
Any tools / tips / suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: There are so many question about using colors on this site i would recommend you to go through with them....

Comment: see this : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for what is called a Color Wheel. And colors can go with multiple other colors...not just one.

It's something some people can see and feel. And using a color wheel allows you to see the combinations in different types...

more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel

Hope this helps.