# Combining colors

Tags: color, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-around-colors-i-select)

I am a developer, and I would like to know how to choose colors that combine together.

I am placing red and blue spots (compulsory colors) over a grass image and I don't know what other colors to choose for the other spots.

- Does anyone know a website, or other resource, that helps decide which colors combine?
- Can anyone suggest a couple of colors that would suit the ones that I've mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this site before to find color palettes: [ColourLovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) might help

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot–
http://colorschemedesigner.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the UX perspective: dont use saturated and bright red and blue together. Not the best for the users eyes when the screen has saturated bright colors from the opposite ends of the color spectrum...

Just desaturate and/or use darker hues when using red and blue together...