# Matching colors for dark brown

Tags: color

I am building a website and need some advice regarding colors.

My [website](http://www.tahara.es) is mostly white and dark brown.

[image]

The logo and menu have to go in that brown color, but I am not sure which seconday color would be good. I picked a reddish pink that matches well with the brown. Any recommendation on other colors that also go well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)

Comment: Hi Samy, welcome to GD.SE! 
I just edited your question a little because it got some close votes (see out [faq](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq) about opinion-based or brainstorming questions). Hopefully you will get some helpful answers. Check this [this recent question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17297/colours-to-use-in-a-fashion-website-other-than-black-and-white-or-white-and-blac). It's been asked recently and it's quite similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the logo and the brown color. It's strong, reliable. I would first try to use this one color for ALL (no gray, lighter brown or black text...) layout elements and not rely on color variation as a design element. Instead I would try using vector graphics / icons as design element.
That said, I tried [this color](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm?cp=492409&ch=25-78-16&cb=492409,E8AA0F,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF) for your subscribe button with white text and quite liked it. This could be a good color for guiding attention when used sparingly.

Answer (score 3):

I think it looks fine as it is, but for a more scientific approach you could try [kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor) It's a great tool for color matching.

Comment: To further expand on that, I would use Kuler, put in your main brown color `#492409` and then play with the color rules and see what things you can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to GD.  As already stated [Adobe Kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor) is a good location for palettes.  Another site to consider would be [colourlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/).  This may be marked as duplicate to [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col).

In another note you must go back to color theory and decide what color you wish to be more powerful.  In this instance you seem to want the brown to power over the palette.  Since the brown alone is strong try toning it down, such as #5E4427.  In regards to the black find a different hue, maybe a flat black, such as #232521, would help get.  The palette should be inviting and flow together.