# Rules for adding colors to a black and white palette in web

Tags: website-design, fonts, color

I am working on a fashion website for my own portfolio, that allows users to have their own account where they save fashion related items. A sort of Pinterest for fashion items.

Now, I know that the most widely used colours for online fashion stores are black and white or white and black. With so much choice, I wondered if it is ok to add tints of other colours, and also what would be a good way to do them. is there a particular set that is best suited? I was thinking of a sleek, modern and retro(ish) design, that is largely flat.

The fonts I'm thinking of using: Gotham Bold, Helvetica + undecided Serif (Bodoni vs Rockwell)

Comment: Hi Elmar, welcome to GD.SE! This quesiton received some close votes because it can be considered as offtopic according to our [faq](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq). I edited so it's less prone to opinion or brainstorming. Please re-edit if you would like to add more info :)

Answer (score 1):

I generally like to think that anything related to a fast-moving industry needs to be current and in 'vogue', with reference to what you need for fashion. Black and white offers a great structural representation of the site and for the most part, a lot of designers online go with it because it allows them to use the colors of the articles to make the visual representation of the items pop.

That said, using neutral tones like browns or darker colors like royal blue might not be so bad if you are using them just as placeholder or mild accents to the overall theme. I can't really say much without seeing something in terms of what you already have and how your site is laying out but going with tints is a little vague when you don't have something to refer to.

Lighter colors also work to provide visual markers for where the user can touch parts of the site for additional information or navigation.

Got anything we can look at?

Comment: I haven't started yet. I like to plan my designs first, so I stick to a pattern, before I open Photoshop. Thanks for your answer.