# Text colours on dark and light

Tags: color, contrast, interface-design, accessibility

I'm trying to create a set of 6 text colours that are to be used on both white and dark purple (42185D) backgrounds (on a web page), and still meet accessibility standards (AA). Are there any tools or guidance that could help? Not a professional graphic designer so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The W3AC provides standards for web accessibility of text. They require specific contrast ratios so it can be read by color blind individuals.

If you know the #hex for your background colors and text colors for your website, it's as easy as inputting them to see if they are AA standards compliant. They can be accessed via [Snook Color Contrast Check](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html)

[image: standards compliant contrast check]

Comment: +1 for Snook. though on a sidenote; browser settings have become pretty easy to set depending on your visual clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely trivial; but there are tools out there. 
You will find a list here: **[Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)**

---

**Edit:** actually [**Color scheme designer**](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) might be a better fit for your use. It has a "colorblind" option.

---

One is [**Adobe Kuler,**](https://kuler.adobe.com/) and you can play around with it like this:

[image]