# What factors do these colors share?

Tags: website-design, color, color-theory, automation, html

Colors below seem to share some kind of "tone" together. For example, colors like [this](http://www.colorhexa.com/0000ff) or [this](http://www.colorhexa.com/ff007f) seem too bright to fit into this group.

What exactly makes this "tone"? I want some technical information, so that if I want to add purple to this group or create a different group of colors, I can find the exact HTML color codes I need.

[image]

Screenshot taken from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less)

Comment: I believe that they all share the same saturation level.

Comment: Oh I know this! All five are in a screen shot you posted to a question!! Did I win, didi I ??? :)

Comment: No @Scott, As Cliff Clavin would answer: "What are five colors that have never been in my kitchen, Alex?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll take a shot. There's nothing unique about the colors you displayed-- they are similar in that they all fall in a small range of both saturation and brightness, but there isn't similar tone or hue to them and they're not under any specific color harmony. (that I'm aware of at least)

As a thought experiment I'm going to take the same colors you provided and rotate all of there hue values 45 degrees.

[image: Original]
[image: 45 degree rotated]

So now we have colors that share the same saturation and brightness as the ones before, however we shifted there hue.

[image: Comparison]

As you can see there is the same amount of relationship technically between the first and second colors, they don't fit a particularly color harmony and to be honest I'm just as uncomfortable saying the first are related as I to saying the second are related.

You are better off creating from known color harmonies, such as a Tetrad color harmony. These are also easier to change programatically because they are based off set hue variations between the colors. In terms of generating a hex code you would need to create a algorithm that converts hsl values into hex or simply use hsl which are supported in CSS although you have a problem with IE8 and below. (There are polyfills that provide support that can be found with a google search)

[image: Tetrad]
[image: Tetrad Wheel]

Comment: Thank you. Tetrad colors give only four colors. So I can probably shift the tetrads to create other colors I need?

Comment: There are many color harmonies, a commonality is that they are usually a set hue value away from each other. What's difficult is that you are trying to apply a programmatic approach to a more objective question of whether colors 'fit' together. The best advice I can give is find a pallete or harmony that you think works and try making hue shifts on all of the colors to see if they still 'fit'

Comment: IMO, your rotated palette has a lot more apparent variation in saturation and luminosity than the original. I'd presume that's because the software you used to rotate it didn't use a gamma-corrected and/or visually uniform color space.

Comment: There's no change in saturation between the colors, only the hue value was rotated. I rechecked and the relative values of saturation and brightness were all the same. You are right though, a hue rotation would slightly change the gamma levels of individual colors. +1 if you explain the relevance of gamma change in perceived brightness because to be honest, I don't quite understand it technically.

Answer (score 1):

Visually, all the colors in your screenshot appear to share a fairly similar [lightness](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightness) and [saturation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness) level.  They're not quite the same, but they're pretty close.

One reason why that's not necessarily obvious from the [RGB](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) or even the [HSL / HSV](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) representation of the colors is that even HSL / HSV is a rather perceptually non-uniform color space: colors that have the same HSL "lightness" value can have very different apparent lightness depending on their hue, and vice versa.

The problem is compounded by the fact that the raw RGB color values you have are most likely [gamma-encoded](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction), and would first have to be converted to a linear color space before you can do any useful colorimetry with them.

If you want to find an additional color that has a similar perceptual lightness and saturation to your original colors, you basically have two options:

1. Just eyeball it.  Start with the simple HSL / HSV representation, change the hue value to what you want, and then manually adjust the lightness and saturation until it looks good.  I suspect this is what the original designer of the palette did.
2. Convert the colors to a perceptually uniform color space like [CIECAM02](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIECAM02) (after gamma-decoding, if necessary), and rotate the hue in that color space.  This should give results the require much less hand-tuning, but unfortunately requires finding some software that supports such a color model (or doing the rather non-trivial math yourself).

Answer (score 0):

This is the Hue parameter changes in [HSB color system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space)

your picture with Hue adjustment

[image]

Comment: Where do these numbers come from? All of these colors seem to have a different HSB values.

Comment: it is very difficult to explain, but the DISTANCE between the parameter is close to be the same through the colors on primary picture. I think, if you want to make similar "tone" - you take any of the colors in the picture and play with a Hue parameter....

Comment: it is not linear dependance though

Comment: Thanks, but I need that difficult explanation so that I can find the exact HTML codes, That was why I started this question. I am a software engineer and not a designer, so I almost know nothing about the color theory.

Comment: probably the easiest way is set HSB color you like and after that convert it to RGB numbers getting hex of R-G-B for the HTML...   ps.I am sure you will get very deep explanation soon...

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but this post might well answer your question? Or is it that you need to generate hex-colour? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col

Comment: Yes, I want to generate the exact HEX color code that share the same "tone". I don't know what this "tone" is officially called, so that's just how I call it for now.

Comment: @CookieMonster the saturation and brightness are close in the "similarly" looking groups colors (like in question), so playing with hue parameter is probably the easiest way to find the appropriate additional color and converting the HSB to hex of RGB.

Comment: @lian, thanks for the comment. But what I am looking for is the mathematical way of computing the exact HEX color code. I don't want to guess it because I need to code this in my application.

Comment: @CookieMonster I have a doubt that the code you are looking for exists... sorry

Comment: could it be that they actually have linear dependence in the original colorspace just that the profile convetsion has whacked it up?