# How do I choose secondary branding colors?

Tags: color, color-theory, branding

How can I make my branding color palette from primary colors?

This is the url with the logo and the primary colors: http://www.onetravel.com/

How can I make other colors?

Comment: There are already many questions and answers on here regarding color matching. Try to use the search function. [This is an interesting thread for example.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)