# Optimal background for an emblem mobile wallpaper?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, background, critique

[image]

I am trying to find the ideal background for this personal emblem that I made to use as a mobile lock screen wallpaper. However, I am spending too much time trying to achieve the ideal background for this. Do you guys have any suggestions on what background and background color(s) would be ideal for this to seamlessly blend into? The current one just doesn't feel right enough. It'll be used for a white iPhone 5's lockscreen. I used adobe illustrator for this. I am leaning towards some gradient look, but open to suggestions. I have a weakness in picking background colors. I would appreciate feedback on the current background and how it is or isn't a good fit for the emblem.

On a side note, if this emblem looks familiar to something else, I would like to know because I would hate to unintentionally be using someone else's as my own.

Edit: So my goal is to make the emblem the center of attention. I don't want strong and dark colors as the background as it tends to take away the attention from the emblem. Light gradient scheme seems to be the best approach, but I don't know which colors to include in the gradient for this 4 color combo to fit seamlessly.

Comment: Hi @brtballin. Seeing that you've got blue, orange, red and purple in your logo, I'd recommend you use a darker version of one of those for your background. Try gradient going from dark, dark purple (almost black) to dark purple. That, or solid black/white.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the response. I tried using your dark purple to purple look and it looked like the background was not letting the emblem "shine" and be the center of attention as much. I want it to look good on the white iPhone border so I feel like going with lighter colors will be the better choice

Comment: Lots of related questions... [This](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/how-can-i-improve-my-color-selection-skill), [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60650/how-to-find-a-good-background-color-for-a-2-color-logo), [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col), [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/colors-in-website-design) and [a lot more...](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=choose+color).

Comment: Hi btrballin, thanks for your post. Please have a look at our [guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682) and see whether you can make your question fit those. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A late addition:

It's ok as is if it's seen as a flying jumbo sized kite, only remove the shadow. A couple of faint clouds in the sky could make it more obvious.

If you want it against some more rich background, there's problems. Very easily your shape takes the 2nd place. Heres one trial to solve the equation:

- used the same colors in a meaningless blurry pattern
- the backround is like seen through grainy glass
- added the contrasts in your shape

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something here : https://qrohlf.com/trianglify-generator/
If you don't want any triangles, just put Variance & Cell Size at minimum.
You got quite some examples to try, and all of them are using radient, maybe it will gave you the idea. Plus, you can download them at the size you want.

Maybe if you reduce the size to the IPhone screen & put some Variance and quite big Cell Size it can do great.