# What website allows you to type in a word and it gives you the associated color?

Tags: color

There is a website that I used to visit that allowed you to type in any word and it would search google images for the word. It would then get the average color of each of the top 20 results from the search. It would then get the average color of the average color from each of those 20 images. It would return that average color. So you could type in anything from "apple" to "Cupertino", and you'd get the most "average" color for that word.

I either simply forgot the web address for this site and it's really hard to find, or it doesn't exist anymore. Does anyone know?

Comment: Unless someone knows it offhand, this question is likely not to be answered

Comment: I  understand, @ZachSaucier, I'm just hoping that someone does know, off the top of their head. It's a helpful tool, so I assumed other people on this forum would know about it - but maybe not...

Comment: Weird but charming question/subject. Thank you for introducing this concept here.

Comment: You can find tools like this and many other color finder tools in [my answer to a related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/63524/23061)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://alexbeals.com/projects/colorize/

Colorize is a website that turns any word or phrase into a hex color. It works by using a search engine to find image results for the word or phrase, and then finding the average color across the approximately 25 image results. Because of this, there's usually a small delay when a word is searched for the first time.

Enjoy.

This is the Google search which I had used to find it for you:
"website turn word into color"

Comment: If you try words like "tea" and "blood" you will see that the concept is interesting but the averages are all rather dull. I found some scientific research-papers today and a lot of effort needs to happen about removing background or irrelevant parts-of-images to auto-create meaningful color-averages.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is one of my favorite tools - I tried googling but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You are welcome, I enjoyed learning about it.

Answer (score 3):

The website I believe you are looking for is Picular. If you haven't tried it yet I suggest you do.
https://picular.co/