# Find a set of colors based off of another set

Tags: website-design, color

new here first off, so if I need to redirect please let me know kindly.

I am a developer and am currently working on front end stuff, and I need to come up with a set of colors for something I am doing based off of another existing set. The colors I have are:

```
color: #8a6d3b; //darker brown yellow
background-color: #fcf8e3; //eggshell yellow
border-color: #faebcc; //slightly darker from above^
```

There exists 4 of these sets of colors, and I want to make my own for use with my web application. I assume though cannot verify that they use some kind of scale to determine these colors. Say they know what they want the `background-color` to be, and then decide they want the `color` to be 50 values below that and the `border-color` to be only 20 values darker than the background. Are there any tools or methods to determine how much variance in the colors there is so if I give a background color, I could then determine the other colors based on the variance?

I'm not versed in the graphic design world/terminology, so hopefully you get the idea of what I am trying to say. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. I looked over that ( see you also answered it so maybe you can elaborate). If I convert say one of the original colors from above, say `background-color` to HSB, do I then do the same with my new `background-color` and the difference between them is the difference between the other parts of the set?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes :)

Comment: Related: [Tools to create a color scheme around chosen colors](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/352/23061)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question, I also sometimes have a hard time to pick a good color palette for a webpage. But some resource that I have found useful are listed below, I hope you find them useful too!

- **AI with Colormind:** Tool using AI and large sample of "good" designs/artwork/prints to generate color combinations. Also possible to supply your own colors and generating complementing colors. http://colormind.io/
- **Structured rules:** Have not seen any unified rules on how to pick great colors yet. But this page takes a stab at it with clear rules on how to do it and with ok results. Start out with your given colors and see where it takes you. https://tallys.github.io/color-theory/
- **Material colors:** Limit the scope of available colors to pick from to a more manageable number. Keeping to combination of them typically yield ok results. [https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette)