# Colors of design are perceived as boring, how can this be improved?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, website-design, critique

I'm working with the same colors all the time and I want to try to make it more interesting. I think the colors are getting boring but I can't just add another color without making it ugly or weird.

**How can I make this design less boring through use of color?**

[[image: Here is what I've got till now.[1]]
Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVug2.png)

Comment: Hi Robbe, I edited your question to give it some more focus. If you disagree with the edits, you can always [edit] it back. Feel free to browse the [help] and specifically the [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).

Comment: Thank you all for answering, I will try all of your advice and try to improve in my designing.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't just add another color without making it ugly or weird.

Have you tried?

In graphic design, a big error is not actually seeing the proposed idea.

You need to **actually work on alternatives**.

- Make a copy of your file and add different colors.
- Try different variations of different color schemes.
- See if the color scheme fit into the project's narrative.

Design is not just about your personal taste. Design is to solve a communication problem.

---

You are using the word Wonder... There is not "much wonder" in that color scheme... or sky for that matter. You are advertising the coldness of space.

Answer (score 1):

Often, adding a random colour will produce a dis-harmoneous result.

Our perception favours some combinations over others as being more aesthetically agreeable. We refer to these combinations as being in harmony. We use other combinations to disrupt harmony to gain attention.

Many years ago, a chemist who also was an amateur artist by the name of Michel Chevreul came up with an organized classification of colours we now call the colour wheel. It has 12 hues which are arranged to display all of the pleasing relationships between and among them. Colours next to one another display adjacent harmony, close ones show analogous harmony, opposites show contrast, every third one shows tetradic colour harmony, every fourth hue shows triadic colour harmony, etc. Pick up a copy of the wheel and some of the concepts relating to harmony to try.

You've already noticed that adding a random colour to those will "clash" and look ugly or weird. After a little practice with the colour wheel with pure hues, you will feel more confident using tints, tones, and shades of the pure hues to produce more refined combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Adobe Color Themes panel to create harmonious colour themes which you can then apply to your design.

To bring up the panel, click *Windows > Color Themes*.  Here are some examples.

[image]

You can also use this without Illustrator, even without an Adobe account.  The color(dot)adobe(dot)com website has similar functionality, plus there are various similar online tools.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col/63524#63524

This answer (and the other ones in that thread) contains a great list of online resources to build color schemes.

Comment: @cetequ Yes, that's a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can add colour without totally ruining the aesthetic of the design you're going for. Going by the vibe I'm getting from what you've done so far I'd suggest trying a monochromatic colour scheme that replaces or tones the greys with different shades of blue.

In many illustrations, you'll see people represent space using shades of blue. Then if you decide you want to change the feel of the design and go for something less reserved try adding a yellow with high contrast dark blue (almost black) text overlayed for CTAs like buttons or of course white will still work.

I've (crudely) made a little adjustment to your design using overlays and showing an example of how it might look in a few colours:

[image: Example of design in Colour]

You might want to stick to mono if that's not the vibe you're looking for but I think it makes it less "boring" as you define it. Also, I know you didn't ask for this advice, but I'd personally up the line height on the body text a smidge (purely personal preference).