# Where to find more to 4 combo colors generator?

Tags: color, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a color combo generator that return me more than "canonical" 4 colors. 
I need 10+ "nice" combo colors .

Can you help me where to find or how to generate by myself?

Comment: this is a broad question; please focus in one problem you want solved. Besides, there are lots of color pallette generators online

Comment: this question on GDSE: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col/63524#63524 has an exhaustive list of color scheme generators, many of which can generate a scheme with more than 4 colors. Is that what you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is likely sort of near a duplicate of [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col/63524#63524). I find that

- [I want Hue](http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/index.php), is good for selecting a good random set of colors for charts.
- [Color brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Set3&n=10), is a has a few well thought out manually picked color palettes for scientific and charting work up to 12 colors. It even advises me when its not CMYK safe.

However please note color is a notoriously bad differentiator, especially if the colors aren't visibly next to each other. Above 6-10 colors your already getting yourself in lot of trouble for selecting colors especially if you need people to be able to read the color.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate them yourself using a 12 hue colour wheel and choosing various different "colour harmony" configurations. There're endless shades or tints of each hue. There is an analogous, complementary, split complementary, triadic, and tetradic colour harmony combinations. Using these "variations" for each hue will give you 10+ "nice" combos.

Or…

Visit: coolors.co, paletton.com, colormind.io, htmlcolorcodes.com, mycolor.space, designmodo.com/color-scheme-generators/, color.adobe.com (Kuler), canva.com/color-palette/, colorschemedesiger.com/csd-3.5/, for a start.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/ is a good platform where you can find different color schemes, change the color harmony and also pick a color from image.

I also prefer https://coolors.co/ for interesting color families and you can also generate your own color scheme.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a preference for https://coolors.co/ . You can choose one colour to start with, then hit space for colours that go with it.

I've found that if I use [Adobe Colour Wheel](https://color.adobe.com), I overthink things and don't use my gut instinct. I always end up picking safe and predictable colours.

For me, there's definitely something in the randomness of Coolors that helps me pick combinations. (Although actually the colours are not actually randomly generated but generated on an algorithm)

Comment: Hi, how do you expand https://coolors.co/ .co to generate 10-12 swatches?

Answer (score 0):

[www.rybcolors.com](http://www.rybcolors.com)
You can pick your combinations from hundreds of shades.