# Large color palette generator?

Tags: color, print-design, website-design, color-theory

Is there a color picker that will generate a large palette of colors say 10 or so? Most I've seen max out at 5. In my case, I have a project that has about 14 color-coded sections and it would be nice to find something that can generate a nice set of colors easily. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: With that many colors, you'd likely be better off using shades of harmonious colors. You can look through [this list of color generators](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/63524/23061) to find some that may help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one which can handle 6: https://galactic.ink/sphere/#.

It's worth pointing out that if you have access to Adobe Illustrator it has a Kuler-type colour scheme building in the recolour toolset which will allow you to add as many pins to a scheme as you need.

---

### EDIT:

OK - though I'm by no means a slavering Adobe Illustrator fan, for this task it does have a good toolset. See images below - less than five minutes to iterate a large number of variant colour schemes starting from your listed 14 colours base point.

Start by purging unused colour swatches - select the items currently coloured in your soon-to-be-base-scheme, and in the swatches palette, click the new folder icon -- this will populate a folder with all the selected item fill colours as swatches - name this something creative like Base Scheme.

Then select items to iterate colour scheme (in my case, the next row of squares) and click on colour guide...

And away we go - remember to make a new colour group each time before editing, and you should end up with a file whose swatches includes a set of folders with discrete colour schemes - and of course, this means you can later individually edit swatches as normal and the items with those swatches applied will update.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping for something that can generate various amounts depending on how large the palette you've inputted. I looked in the edit colors portion of Illustrator and perhaps I'm not seeing it but it seems rather cumbersome to build a scheme that way. Might be better off just creating one on the canvas. Of course, I could be missing something.

Comment: @ErickP - I've updated my answer to address your comment - hopefully that helps more than my previous attempt!

Comment: Thank you for the update. It's very helpful.