# Picking distinctive colors for close wireframe drawings?

Tags: color, palette

I am working on a video game level editor, here you have a wireframe rendering that shows various properties, each having a unique color but it's hardly clear to be honest:

[image]

Now if I zoom in, things are more clear, base is gray, floors are semi-white, walls are semi-black:

[image]
Somehow I managed to get a bit of clarity, I render features with different sizes:

[image]

But as a pile things up, things start to look really terrible:

(okay, this is one is fully zoomed out so I'm not expecting the clearest render but still)

[image]

Obviously I can turn things off at will, but it's more about finding a pleasant color scheme:

[image]

Picking good colors for clarity is something I found more difficult than it sounds !

**Question:**

What's a good approach to pick colors for thin lines that'll be rendered very close to each other?

Comment: Color choicse can not help with your information retention. Color is a bad mnemonic.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)

Comment: Yes, sort of, thanks!