# Color palette generator method for website sections

Tags: color, palette

I want to generate a color palette using [coolors.co](https://coolors.co/) using this green color (#24855E) as a starting point but I don't know which option to select to generate a palete like the example below.

[image]

I was inspired by this website (https://1password.com/) which has a starting color of blu found in the logo (#1471CE) then the background sections are different colors such as:

Hero header section (background color:  #0372EC )
[image]

Second section (background color: #0A2D4D)
[image]

Third section (background color: #E8F3FF)
[image]

What generator method should I use to get similar 3 shades of blu but, instead of using #1471CE as a starting color, using this green (#24855E) ?

Comment: Do the colors *have* to be generated by a site? If you already know what you want, it seems strange to search for a site that gives that result instead of just making the colors yourself and have full control.

Comment: I have only the starting color, I don't know a method to generate other 2 colors. Like the same method used by 1password.

Comment: I mean try different colors to see what works? Test it in some drawing application, or experiment with the color picker in developer tools in the browser.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the same "transformation" applied to a starting color to another?

Comment: If you have a client there, they will likely end up choosing the colors for you :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a monochromatic palette with a base colour of #24855E. I tried using the site you linked to but can't work out how to do it. Maybe I'm too stupid, but it shouldn't be this difficult.

You could do it using the Adobe Color site however. The service is free. I have no affiliation with Adobe or the Adobe Color website.

1. Choose the monochromatic option
2. Set the base colour (middle swatch) to #24855E. A palette will be generated.
3. Change to HSB color model.
4. If required, switch to the Custom option and move the saturation and brightness sliders to adjust the other colours.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. All these green looks sickly on a website. Do you suggest following this strategy (monochromatic) or other harmony rules (triad, complementary etc.) ?

Comment: @sparkle Those other harmony rules would introduce other hues into the mix. But sure, do what you want. There are no real rules when choosing colours. It's more about what you like or what your client would like. Colour choice is subjective

Answer (score 1):

> I want to generate a color palette using coolors.co using this green
> color (#24855E) as a starting point but I don't know which option to
> select to generate a palete like the example below.

### Learning comes from experimentation.

Designing, and in this particular situation, picking some colors with a random tool, is not an exact science. Try every option until you get something that works and that your client approves.

Try another tool: [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)

Yes, there will be versions and revisions. Yes, that is also learning.

Comment: I was looking for a math transformation between #1471CE and #0372EC and apply the same to #24855E

Comment: @sparkle, but colors are more complicated than you assume. Try for example looking at the different colors as [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). You can use a site like [this](https://colordesigner.io/convert/hextohsl). The blue base color is HSL(211,97,47) and your green base color is HSL(156,57,33). So they do not have the same properties to begin with and therefore you can't expect to be able to do the same mathematical conversion. (I'm just scratching the surface here.)

Comment: @sparkle dont get confused by name appropriation from natural sciences. Color theory does not tell you how to pick colors. It begins by reasoning about how to mix colors and ends up telling you that if you use these colors you get these kinds of results most of the time. So theres no direct mathematical way to suggest good colors coming out of these color harmonies because there is only a very wague basis of these claims. Worse we dont exactly know how the color wheel should be constructed. This means theres no mathematical basis since we can not agree on the coordinates.

Comment: So at the end of the day you can have multiple different mappings that are all more or less valid.