# How can I quickly find a matching color without professional skills?

Tags: color-theory

[image]

I'm using PowerPoint to draw some diagrams for my thesis. I found that many papers had beautifully drawn pictures. But when I make it myself, it's always weird.

I'm wondering if it's possible to quickly pick some matching colors. For example, in the picture below, how should I set the color of each box to be more appropriate?

1. For example, using PowerPoint, is it appropriate to choose a color and then adjust different transparency?
2. Or select the color of a certain column?

Is there a fixed option for this?

Really Thanks!!!

Comment: PowerPoint has "theme colors", have you tried merely sticking to those?

Comment: You can try using one of the countless [color pickers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/63524/23061) out there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)