# How to expand a simple palette?

Tags: color, color-theory, palette

I grabbed a fun little neon palette from Paletton (below), and I want to try editing a photo (that I've reduced to a 256-color indexed colormap) to be in the neon palette. I'd like to get more nuanced in the 15-color palette from Paletton, ideally up to 256 colors.

Is there a good method for generating a more nuanced palette from a simple one? Or is there a way to elaborate the palette by referencing the differences in color in my source photo, or something like that? Or is there a principal of color theory I can use to expand it more manually?

Palette:

*** Primary color:

shade 0 = #213FFF
shade 1 = #AFBAFF
shade 2 = #8394FF
shade 3 = #001595
shade 4 = #001073

*** Secondary color (1):

shade 0 = #FF00B9
shade 1 = #FFA4E6
shade 2 = #FF70D8
shade 3 = #A20075
shade 4 = #7D005A

*** Secondary color (2):

shade 0 = #35FF00
shade 1 = #B7FFA4
shade 2 = #8EFF70
shade 3 = #26B700
shade 4 = #1D8C00

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What kind of edit/result are you looking to achieve? It's quite hard to answer this without seeing anything. Changing an image into Indexed colour is unlikely to make editing easy. Usually Indexed colour would be something you do after making an edit to a normal RGB image, essentially the last step. Is there some reason you need an Indexed colour image? Also what software are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)

Comment: It would be really helpful if you both showed us how the palette looks (so we don't have to enter the 15 hex codes ourselves), the original image you want to change and some example of the result you expect. Changing the colors of an image to match a palette isn't a simple thing to do. Might require manual work, might not be possible for that particular image.

Answer (score 1):

There's some tools for colour blending/interpolation.

[planetcalc.com/5799/](https://planetcalc.com/5799/)

Or you could code something yourself.

[codepen.io/njmcode/pen/NWdYBy](https://codepen.io/njmcode/pen/NWdYBy)