# Good color to go with black & white design?

Tags: color, color-theory

What's a good color to go with a black and white design, if there will only be one color on the site? I've tried using color palettes but they're not very helpful, because if the first two colors are black and white, the third will be a shade of gray.

What sort of principle should I use to choose a color?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any colour works with black and white.

Any colour you pick will be effectively an accent colour. This gives you free reign to **pick what ever colour will be most effective for the communication of your design intent**.

Red is often used with a black and white palette since it is both a bold, powerful colour with a huge number of associated connotations. this makes it very flexible for communicating a number of different things at once dependant on context. Read up on the answers for [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2/79) for further information.

Just as important as *what colour*, is understanding how to powerfully use colour, especially in a black and white design. A 'black and white + accent colour' design will find its strength in restaint, it is essentially a minimalist colour palette, and will lose effect if colour is applied too liberally. Careful placement of colour can be used to link elements together, or highlight constrasting elements (or ideas, i.e love and war with red)

Comment: Naturally choose a color in base of what are you talking about. For example for a website of oranges I would have put orange. For a Mac Donald website, i would choose Red and yellow. For a website of computers I would choose the blue. It help to define subtly about what are you talking.

Answer (score 2):

As Jaips said any color will go with black and white.

It all depends on how do you want your site to look. Dark or light ...you can use tools like

http://kuler.adobe.com

to figure this out. On this website you can go to the home page and enter "black white" in search box and press search button. Website will generate different themes for you including the colors you are searching.

Peace,
Ved

Answer (score -1):

You can use any color color with white and black as an combination. If you are using light or dark gray with gray to make contrast.. Go for it. It also look very attractive.

If you have still any confusion, here are some popular website for Designers to choose color combinations.

Try these, it will help you.

http://paletton.com/#uid=1000u0kllllaFw0g0qFqFg0w0aF

http://www.colorcombos.com/black-and-white-color-schemes.html

http://www.colourlovers.com/web/palettes

https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/