# Colors combinations and and how to pick a color

Tags: color, color-theory

i am new to designing and i have a huge problem. I can easily generate ideas of layout how they should look but my biggest problem is that i can't or is very hard for me to get suitable colours and their combination. How can i improve my colour feeling and to get rid off this problem?

Comment: See also http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sources-for-color-theory-or-psychology-of-color