# Core color theory books books for UI/UX specialist

Tags: color, interface-design, color-theory, style

I'm a newbie at design. I'm a front-end developer mostly working at tech issues rather than business or design. I really want to get some useful knowledge in this field to help my team to build better software. So, what i really want to get first is some books about color theory and how to choose an appropriate color theme for UI. It would be awesome if you can provide me the book where i can find not only the rules about building and mixing colors, but explaining as well, why these colors are more suitable for people's perception etc.

Thanks a lot.

P.S. To anticipate "on hold" status due to "recommendation question" i'd like to tell you that i'm not talking about subjective recommendation/opinion, but core color theory books that might exist and must have to be read by anyone who wants to deep into this. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be looking for a UI/UX designer instead of a color theory book... Unless you want to make a career switch. A FE is not really the person who should be deciding on colors and ui.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sources for Color Theory or Psychology of Color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sources-for-color-theory-or-psychology-of-color)

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 To be fair, there's not always a designer at small companies.

Comment: @ZachSaucier But should that be the FE's problem? If he is interested in becoming a designer as well it could be valuable, otherwise I would look for a designer.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. This is not FE issues, but that's what i want to learn for myself first.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Sometimes it's not a matter of what *should* be their problem. Sometimes it's a matter of what *has* to be in order for the company to do alright